# Finding where <<loop>> happened

Tags: debugging, haskell, infinite-loop

If we get a `<<loop>>`, it means that Haskell had managed to detect an infinite loop. Is there a way to get ghc to tell us where this loop happened? It seems that Haskell should have this information somewhere.

Comment: How is this related with halting problem? GHC is already telling us that there _is_ a loop.

Comment: @sinan Sorry, I thought it wanted to detect infinite loop.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Compile your app with `-prof` and `-fprof-auto`(if you're using Cabal, use `--enable-executable-profiling` and `--ghc-options=-fprof-auto`) and then run it with  `+RTS -xc`. It'll print a stack trace when errors happen. This should help you narrow your scope.

Example:

```
➜  haskell  cat loop.hs 
myFun :: Int
myFun =
    let g = g + 1
    in g + 10

main = print myFun
➜  haskell  ghc loop.hs -prof -fprof-auto
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( loop.hs, loop.o )
Linking loop ...
➜  haskell  ./loop +RTS -xc                             
*** Exception (reporting due to +RTS -xc): (THUNK_STATIC), stack trace: 
  Main.myFun.g,
  called from Main.myFun,
  called from Main.CAF
*** Exception (reporting due to +RTS -xc): (THUNK_STATIC), stack trace: 
  Main.myFun.g,
  called from Main.myFun,
  called from Main.CAF
loop: <<loop>>
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what has already been written: These loops are only detected at *run-time*. The detection is based on the code attempting to evaluate a value which is already being evaluated [by the same thread]. Clearly that should never happen.

If you're looking for a compiler switch to detect this at *compile-time*... you're out of luck. It's easy enough to statically spot recursion, but deciding whether the recursion is infinite or not isn't so easy.